# Numpy sum and product over multiple arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

Suppose we are given an array `M` of arrays with different shapes. E.g.

```
import numpy as np

M = []
for i, j in [3,5], [2,2], [6,3]:
    M.append(np.random.rand(i, j))
```

I need to perform actions such as sums and products over the axes of this fancy 3D array. Performance is crucial, so I do not want to loop manually over the subarrays of `M`.

Extending the bounds of the subarrays and filling them with zeros so that all axes have the same length is not an option, as only very few subarrays are large and most of the subarrays are small. Furthermore, incorporating additional zeros in the operations would change the results (e.g. when multiplying along an axis).

As I am not aware of an array data structure that is both efficient and allows subaxes of different lengths, I was thinking of storing the data in a 1D array and performing the operation via some kind of fancy slicing over subsections of the array. I suppose this is how it is done with the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

If I am given an array `indptr` of row start and end points (such as `indptr` in `csr_matrix`), how could I efficiently construct the array

```
[f(M[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]) for i in len(M)]
```

without pure python (i.e. with numpy operations)? Here, `f(...)` would be e.g. a sum or product or multiplication with a constant.

As the `csr_matrix` seems to implement this functionality, I have attempted a first solution by repeatedly creating sparse matrices and summing over their axis.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# prepare the creation of the sparse matrices

indptr1 = [0]
indices1 = []

indptr2 = [0]
indices2 = []

data = []

for submatrix in M:
    indptr2.append(indptr2[-1]+len(submatrix))
    indices2.extend(range(len(submatrix)))
    for row in submatrix:
        indices1.extend(range(len(row)))
        indptr1.append(indptr1[-1]+len(row))
        data.extend(row)

matrix1 = csr_matrix((data, indices1, indptr1))

# sum over the first axis
intermediate_result = matrix1.sum(1)

matrix2 = csr_matrix((np.asarray(intermediate_result).ravel(), indices2, indptr2))

# sum over the second axis
result = matrix2.sum(1)
```

However, the detour via `csr_matrix` seems to be a little bit hacky to me. Furthermore, I am not sure how efficient `csr_matrix` actually is. How could I do this withouth the overhead of creating multiple matrices?

I am sure the necessary code must be somwhere if `csr_matrix` can do it.

Comment: Sparse matrices are worth using only if sparsity is 1% or less. They are optimized for matrix products - in fact things like row sums and indexing actually use matrix multiplication.

Comment: @hpaulj Does this mean that the row sums and producs of `csr_matrix` are just doing matrix multiplication internally? I am aware that I am 'abusing' the sparse matrix data type. However, is there a good alternative?

Comment: See my answer to another recent sparse question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62217382/901925

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. This is helpful and explains why my current approach via sparse matrices does not work. The original problem remains, though.

Comment: It seems to me that you're wildly better off storing the sums and products of each subarray and then combining them appropriately. I would also take a step back and consider other solutions to whatever your original problem is, instead of this solution you seem to be locked into.

Comment: @CJR Do you mean to loop over the arrays in a `for` loop? The original problem is a likelihood maximization. The likelihood functino is quite complicated, which is why performance is key. I do not think that there is a different formulization of the ogininal problem.